# How to give runtime padding and margin in Android

Tags: android

I created checkbox dynamically according to size of list. Now I want to give margin top to each checkbox at runtime dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

Use LinearLayout.LayoutParam or RelativeLayout.Layoutparam:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
buttonLayoutParams.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);
checkBox.setLayoutParams(buttonLayoutParams);
```

Comment: @Gauravsappal you can upvote the answer if it works for you.